# css transition opacity of the background color

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

looking for clue, how to use the opacity in background color with transition?

I'm using `rgba()` function, but the transition is not working on hover.

```css
.bx{
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  width:100px; height:100px;
  position:relative;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}

.bx:hover{
  background:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

.t{
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="bx"><div class="t">text</div></div>
```

Any idea, how can I use transition for `.bx`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In fact, `opacity` and `rgba()` are completely different.

Since you are using the `rgba()` as the background color by the `background` property, you'll need to use `background` as transition property as follows:

```css
.bx {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  width:100px; height:100px;
  position: relative;

  -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background .5s ease-out;
  transition: background .5s ease-out;
}

.bx:hover {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/EgEN/1/edit)**.

Comment: Agreed. The opacity hasn't been altered so the transition would do nothin attached to it.

Comment: TIL; It is worth noting that animating the background is significantly more expensive than animating opacity (as it causes repaints). Noticeable when you have many elements animating simultaneously or on low powered devices!

Comment: is there a reason why i cannot `transition` the opacity of an `rgba` value of the `color` property? the transition is always instant :(