# CSS3: Transition of background color to transparent

Tags: html, css, dom

I want to do a transition in a `div` that:

- Starts with `background-color:rgba(242, 245, 169, 1);`

  ... and after 3 seconds...
- Ends with    `background-color:rgba(242, 245, 169, 0);`

And... Between the two fases shows `background-color:rgba(242, 245, 169, 0.9);` , `background-color:rgba(242, 245, 169, 0,8);`, `background-color:rgba(242, 245, 169, 0.7);`...

Similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18353355/4467741), but **without the ':hover'**. Directly.

### How can I get it?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use animation and not transition

Comment: Have a look at keyframes. That's what you want.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/hakomq5L/

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: fade 3s forwards;
    background-color:rgba(242, 245, 169, 1);
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {background-color:rgba(242, 245, 169, 1);}
    to {background-color:rgba(242, 245, 169, 0);}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use animation for that. My solution is reusable, because I use opacity property, so you can use any color you want.

**Working JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5m1pb227/1/**

HTML

```
<div class="box">
```

CSS

```
.box {
  background-color:rgb(242, 245, 169);
  width:100px; height:100px;
  position: relative;
  animation: myfadeIn 2s;  
}


@keyframes myfadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other correct answers, if the hover element is not a div but a link, and you are transitioning to/from an rgba color, Chrome 62 will not transition it unless you specify the link is not inline, ie:

CSS

```
a {display:inline-block;}
```

If the hover element is left displayed inline, for some reason Chrome won't animate the transition.