# JavaScript fading effect for div

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("script_"+el);
elem.style.opacity = 0.5;
elem.style.transition = "opacity 1s";
```

I then later on down in the code have

```
elem.style.opacity = 1;
```

I was expecting the div to first load the opacity (0.5), then load the higher opacity and add the transition effect and move from the Opacity 0.5 -> 1, I saw this happen in a JavaScript tutorial but it doesn't seem to be working for my div and my content.

Comment: vendor specification is important while dealing with transition.

Comment: Are you sure the element is being selected and it exists? Check the developer console for errors.

Comment: Can you create a demo of your issue?

Comment: @Oisin the element is being selected, I did look in the console and there are no errors with it

Comment: Try using elem.animate().

Comment: Why not create a CSS class to do this, and then get the element and add the CSS class's which have the transition and opacity change

Comment: @oisin the `animate()` method isn't present in JavaScript, though it's available in libraries; but since no library is tagged it's probably best to assume none is being used, rather than introducing a dependency (though there are, of course, advantages to using a library regardless of the cost of a dependency).

Comment: Here is my example https://jsfiddle.net/hcw0x43c/ @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: Duplicate: [css transition opacity of the background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353274/css-transition-opacity-of-the-background-color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a delay after setting the transition property,

```
  var elem = document.getElementById("script_"+el);
  elem.style.opacity = 0.1;
  elem.style.transition = "opacity 1s";
  setTimeout(function(){ elem.style.opacity = 1;} , 50);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hcw0x43c/1/)

Or the best way would be adding that transition through css. That would not expect the engine to make some delay before detecting the target property.

Comment: Works great! Thanks :)

Comment: @Jek Glad to help! :)